# How to get nested field from ASP.NET Core form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the example below, a complex ViewModel contains the property "ExampleEntity.Name". How can this nested property from a complex view model be retrieved from a controller in ASP.NET Core?

**Form field with nested property "Entity1.Name"**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string ExampleEntity.Name) // This does not work
{

}
```

Comment: You need to have the same model object in the parameter as it is used in the view.

Comment: Isn't it possible not having to bind to a strongly typed object for every field? Could you provide an example of what you are meaning as an answer to this question?

Comment: You can accept a `FormCollection` parameter or simply retrieve the value from `Request.Form`

Comment: @abdusco could you provide an example as an answer to this question.

Comment: Or you can have `Update(WhateverYourOriginalModelClassWasCalled model)` to bind it to the same structure as was used to build the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a form like this:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" />    
</form>
```

you can read the value of that field with:

### 1. `[FromForm]` attribute:

Annotate an action parameter of suitable type with `FromForm` and denote which field its value should be sourced from.

You can accept a class parameter with a prefix:

```cs
public void OnPost([FromForm(Name = "ExampleEntity")] ExampleEntity model)
{
   // model is filled with form fields that start with "ExampleEntity."
}
```

Or specify a particular field and read its value:

```cs
public void OnPost([FromForm(Name = "ExampleEntity.Name")] string name)
{
    // name is populated from the form's `ExampleEntity.Name` field
}
```

### 2. `IFormCollection`:

You can go deeper and accept a `IFormCollection` inside your action and read the form values from it:

```cs
public void OnPost(IFormCollection form)
{
    var exampleEntityName = form["ExampleEntity.Name"];
}
```

or even deeper:

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    var exampleEntityName = Request.Form["ExampleEntity.Name"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project,using `string ExampleEntity.Name` will get error.Asp.net core bind data with `name` attribute,so if you only want to bind the value of `<input asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="form-control" />`,you can change the `name` attribute of Input.
Here is a demo：

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" name="Name" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ExampleEntity.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string Name)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method in Model:

```
  public void OnPost()
    {
        var inputName = Request.Form["inputName"];
        // do something with inputName
        ViewData["test"] = inputName;
    }
```

How it can be used in view:

```
<form method="post"><input type="text" name="inputName" value="123" class="form-control" /><button type="submit">submite</button><div>@ViewData["test"]</div></form>
```